# Microchip dsPIC33 C30 function pointer size?

Tags: function-pointers

The C30 user manual manual states that pointers near and far are 16bits wide.
How then does this address the full code memory space which is 24bits wide?

I am so confused as I have an assembler function (called from C) returning the program counter (from the stack) where a trap error occurred. I am pretty sure it sets w1 and w0 before returning.

In C, the return value is defined as a function pointer:

```
void (*errLoc)(void);
```

and the call is:

```
errLoc = getErrLoc();
```

When I now look at errLoc, it is a 16 bit value and I just do not think that is right. Or is it? Can function pointers (or any pointers) not access the full code address space?

All this has to do with a TRAP Adress error I am trying to figure out for the past 48 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are trying to use the `dsPIC33Fxxxx/PIC24Hxxxx` fault interrupt trap example code.

The problem is that pointer size for dsPIC33 (via the MPLAB X C30 compiler) is 16bit wide, but the program counter is 24bits. Fortunately the `getErrLoc()` assembly function does return the correct size.

However the example C source code function signature provided is `void (*getErrLoc(void))(void)` which is incorrect as it will be treating the return values as if it was a 16bit pointer. You want to change the return type of the function signature to be large enough to store the 24bits program counter value below instead. Thus if you choose unsigned long integer as the return type of `getErrLoc()`, then it will be large enough to store the 24bit program counter into a 32bit unsigned long integer location.

```
unsigned long getErrLoc(void);  // Get Address Error Loc
unsigned long errLoc __attribute__((persistent));
```

(FYI: Using `__attribute__((persistent))` to record trap location on next reboot)

Comment: Not a problem. I do wonder how to figure out how to do a stack unwinding in it however.